# Django Allauth facebook login error " App isn't using a secure connection to transfer information"

Tags: python, django, django-allauth

I am trying to integrate facebook login to my website https://thelittlechamp.com. You can try by clicking the facebook login button in the nav bar. While trying to log in it says "Facebook has detected thelittlechamp isn't using a secure connection to transfer information". I am using django-allauth library. I couldnt figure out the main reason behind the error. If someone know please help me.

Answer (score 0):

You used an HTTP protocol for the Facebook login method. I'm attaching below the source-code taken from your very site:

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script id="allauth-facebook-settings" type="application/json">
{"appId": "669910837179987", "version": "v7.0", "sdkUrl": "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js", "initParams": {"appId": "669910837179987", "version": "v7.0", "cookie": true}, "loginOptions": {"scope": "email,public_profile"}, "loginByTokenUrl": "http://thelittlechamp.com/accounts/facebook/login/token/", "cancelUrl": "http://thelittlechamp.com/accounts/social/login/cancelled/", "logoutUrl": "http://thelittlechamp.com/accounts/logout/", "loginUrl": "http://thelittlechamp.com/accounts/facebook/login/", "errorUrl": "http://thelittlechamp.com/accounts/social/login/error/", "csrfToken": "Z8NGWyWh9HxaM7BCUfZkdV7WvqYvGiOp5UZz023enBY1SjqwqBcTFRHcjGlbCEcq"}
</script>
```

As you can see, despite the fact that your site is actually running on an HTTPS secure protocol, the request issued to Facebook's API (or OAuth, doesn't really matter) specifies your site with an HTTP initial. The moment you fix it, this bug should be solved.

Comment: I am still struggling with the same problem. Do you know any idea how can i fix this? Please suggest me.

Comment: Hey mate. You need to configure your default HTTP request to HTTPS: you should find the following line in your settings: ACCOUNT_DEFAULT_HTTP_PROTOCOL (=”http”) and change it to "https". you can find more information on the docs: https://django-allauth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/configuration.html and: https://django-allauth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced.html?highlight=https By the way, if you found my answer helpful please feel free to upvote it and accept it as the correct answer.